# Eclipse doesn't provide quick fix option for Python as it does for Java

Tags: java, python, eclipse, pydev

I would like to see quick fixes option in Eclipse for Python. Is there any way to configure it?

For example: In Java, if I don't provide a package name for InputStream, then Eclipse recommends few package options (as shown in below image).

[image: Quick Fixes Option in Eclipse for Java]

But the same is not happening for PyDev Editor. For suppose, if I don't enter SimpleProducer library, then eclipse doesn't provide any recommendations to fix it (as shown in below image).

[image: No Quick Fix Option in Eclipse for Python]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you press `Ctrl` + `1`?

Comment: I didn't try before. 
Your suggestion works and that is what I am looking for. 
Thanks Klaus!

Comment: @KlausD. Can you please post your comment as an answer. I would like to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Quick Fix / Content Assistants feature of PyDev is activated with the key combination `Ctrl` + `1`.

There are also some other good to know key combinations listed at http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_keybindings.html